# How to create a table in a blob storage using U-SQL

Tags: blob, u-sql

Is it possible to use U-sql to create a table under a specified blob storage?
If so could you provide me an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Azure Tables, there is no capability in U-SQL yet to access Azure Tables. You should use Azure Data Factory to move data from ADLS to Azure Tables.

If you mean Azure Blob Storage, you can register your blob storage account with your ADL account (via the portal or the relevant Azure ADL Powershell command) and then create a file inside the blob store with `OUTPUT @result TO "wasb://container@account/path" USING ...`.